# show echo if column is empty else show another echo

Tags: php

i wrote this code but there is some mistake its only shows the first echo even if the column is not empty.

i wnat the code to show echo "1" if the column subuser1 is empty
else to show echo "2" if the column subuser1 is not empty.

```
  <?php

  include_once 'dbconnect.php';

   // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DBNAME);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}  

$sql= ("SELECT subuser1 FROM users WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user']  );
$result = $conn->query($sql);


$subuser1 = $row["subuser1"];


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

if (empty($subuser1)) {

echo "subuser1 is either 0, empty, or not set at all";
}
 } else {
echo " subuser1 not empty";
```

Comment: if($subuser1 == NULL || $subuser1 == "" || $subuser1 == "0" )

Comment: sorry its not working

Comment: it dosnt show any thing not working

Comment: I don't know what your other problems are but there is no `$row` in your code: `$row = $result->mysqli_fetch_assoc();` Good luck.

Comment: The closing `}` is also missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it like that it works perfect if anyone need it.

```
 <?php
 $userR= 0 ;
 include_once 'dbconnect.php';

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DBNAME);
 // Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}  

$sql= ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user']  );
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  

  if ($row["subuser1"] == NULL ){
 echo "";  }
   else {

echo " bla bla bla "
}
}
?>
```